# getting standard errors for predicted values from model averaged mixed generalized linear models (GLMM)

Tags: lme4

I am using model.avg to make multi-model inferences on a suite of mixed effects generalized linear models (GLMMs) derived with LMER. I can use PREDICT to get predicted values but cannot get standard errors for those predicted values because of the random effects:

```
Error in predict.averaging(Mod.avg, newdata, se.fit = TRUE) : 
   'predict' for models '' caused errors
In addition: Warning messages:
    1: In predict.merMod(object = <S4 object of class "lmerMod">, newdata  = newdata,  : cannot calculate predictions with both standard errors and random effects
```

I've tried using predictInterval and bootMer (merTools) but they can't handle the model.avg object:

```
Error in UseMethod("getME") : 
   no applicable method for 'getME' applied to an object of class "averaging"
```

Does anyone have a work-around to derived confidence intervals and standard errors in this situation?